# Como realizar peticion post a una api con ssl desde python

Tags: python, api, ssl, odoo

Resulta que estoy intentando realizar la conexion a una api que posee autenticacion basica por lo que necesito enviar usuario y contraseña, la url es con https, y aunque he probado varias opciones, siempre recibo el mismo error. La peticion la estoy realizando con python desde odoo.
Decir ademas que he probado la conexion desde postman y funciona perfectamente.

La peticion la realizo de la siguiente forma:

```
headers = {'charset': 'UTF-8', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
response = requests.post(
    url, 
    headers=headers, 
    auth=(username, password), 
)
data = unescape(
    etree.tostring(generateXML.create_xml(data)).decode()), 
    verify=False
)
```

Error recibido:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='url_host', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /preregistroenvios?wsdl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_ske_dhe', 'dh key too small')])")))
```

Podrian ayudarme a solucionar este error?

Comment: Has configurado los headers? El método de autenticacion? , como haces la petición? Añade esto último a tu pregunta

Comment: Ya he agregado los datos que me pides, lo que esta dentro del data no es mas que un xml que se genera bien, que le tengo que enviar a la api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es tuyo sino del servidor. Está usando para SSL un sistema de cifrado que se considera inseguro (una clave Diffie-Hellman débil). Las versiones recientes de la librería OpenSSL (como la que Python estará usando en tu script) rechazan esas claves por motivos de seguridad.

Posibles soluciones (no he probado ninguna, sólo las he encontrado en diferentes sitios de internet):

1. Editar `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` y modificar la línea `CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2` para cambiar el 2 por un 1. Eso permite (en teoría) una clave DH insegura como la que usa tu servidor. Esto serviría si tu script python se ejecuta desde un unix, en el que este archivo exista.
2. Usar la siguiente línea en tu script python:

   ```
   requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=1'
   ```

   Esto (en teoría) equivaldría al punto 1, pero si necesidad de modificar la configuración de OpenSSL a nivel global.
3. Modificar el script python para configurar `requests` con un conjunto de algoritmos de cifrado diferente al que usa por defecto, para excluir de ese conjunto los que usen Diffie-Hellman. Esto es complejo, no he encontrado cómo hacerlo, y en todo caso podría fallar si el servidor sólo soporta los algoritmos de intercambio de claves basados en Diffie-Hellman.
4. Ponerte en contacto con el admin del servidor y pedirle que reconfigure SSL para que no use una clave DH débil. Esta sería una buena opción para además proteger al servidor frente a ataques conocidos debido a esa debilidad.

Comment: Gracias de antemano por la ayuda brindada.... Resulta que ahora obtengo un error diferente al que recibia antes: 401 Authorization Required - This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested.  Either you supplied the wrong\ncredentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required. Y puedo asegurar que esta bien el usuario y la contraseña, quizas es por la forma en la que envio los datos de Basic Auth que no es asi.

Comment: Lo he solucionado agregando lo siguiente:  encoded_credentials = base64.b64encode(bytes(f'{username}:{password}', encoding='ascii')).decode('ascii')
            auth_header = f'Basic {encoded_credentials}'

            headers = {"Authorization": auth_header, 'charset': 'UTF-8', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}